# Dependency injection: rest and default function parameters for the same function?

Tags: javascript, testing, dependency-injection

Say I have some code like this:

```
function a(...numbers) {
   return numbers.map(n => b(n)); 
}

function b(n) {
   return n+1; 
}
```

I've been looking at ways I would test like code like this, specifically to test the functionality of `a` without actually calling `b`.

One option is to use dependency injection, and to pass function b as a parameter.

ie.

```
function a(...numbers, _b=b) {
   return numbers.map(n => _b(n)); 
}
```

But of course, the rest operator won't allow me to tack an argument on the end.

And I don't want to put the function argument  first - because then the developer is having to have to pass function b in every time, or whatever, or pass a null value or similar.

Is there a way you could achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (kinda) solves this!

```js
//The convention we will use here is that developers shouldn't use the 
// _underscore methods in production. 

export const _a = function(_b, ...numbers) {
 return numbers.map(n => _b(n)); 
}; 

export const b = function(n) {
  return n+1; 
}

export const a = _a.bind(null, b); 

console.log(a(1,2,3)) //[2,3,4]
```

This also has the advantage of that you're hiding the injected function from the developer.

Now how would you test this?

You have to test the _underscore method, so something like:

```
import { _a } from "../functions";

describe("_a", () => {

    it("_a(1,2,3) calls _b three times.", () => {
        const mockFn = jest.fn();
        const a = _a.bind(null, mockFn);

        a(1, 2, 3);

        expect(mockFn.mock.calls).toHaveLength(3);
    })

});
```

If you're interested - I've started a [Github repo with a more fleshed out example of this approach here](https://github.com/dwjohnston/testing_with_jest/tree/master/dependencyInjection).

If anyone has a tidier way of doing this - I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

rest parameters can only work as the last argument accepted by a function, it captures all argumets that were not declared in the function parameter. You can actually let go of the rest parameter and pass in an array

```
function a(numbers, _b = b) {
   return numbers.map(n => _b(n)); 
}

function b(n) {
   return n+1; 
}

console.log(a([1,2,3,4], f => f * 1));
```

Comment: But then I have to always pass an array as an argument.

Comment: then you should use our old friend `arguments`